# How do I get access to the .git path when building on TeamCity?

Tags: git, teamcity

At build time on TeamCity I want to interrogate the .git directory.
So how do I get access to that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, that .git directory should be right under the "[Build Checkout directory](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Checkout+Directory)".

> In your **[build script](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)** you may refer to the effective value of build checkout directory via the **`teamcity.build.checkoutDir`** property provided by TeamCity.

Note: Ensure "VCS checkout mode" is set to "Automatically on agent"